# Error not being passed back to struts jsp

Tags: struts2

This worked a month ago and now i reload the code and it doesn't work.  here is my struts snip

```
    <action name="checkManager" class="CheckAction">
        <result>/pages/check_manager.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="submitFile" class="SubmitFileAction">
        <result name="success">/pages/submit_file.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/pages/check_manager.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

So, the first page is `checkManager`.  it has a button that calls the `submitFile` action.  When that fires, it checks a password, if it fails the action class sends an error result.  Now a month ago the result error above would redirect the user back to the original `check_manager.jsp` page complete with data that was loaded originally and the error message.  Today, it redirects the user to the raw `check_manager.jsp` page.  no data, its like the servlet never fired and its just rendering a blank jsp page.  I checked the source history and nothing has changed in this application.

I don't understand why this would stop working, can anyone give me an idea?  i have to present this to the client in about an hour and a half so i'm really stuck here.

note, i tried changing the error to this

```
<result name="error" type="redirectAction">checkManager</result>
```

and I get my data back, but i loose my error message which isn't a good thing.  ugh, any ideas?

```
if (enteredHash.equals(storedHash)) {
            _log.debug("The password matched");
            UserSession<User> userSession = (UserSession<User>) session
                    .get("user");
            #do logic#
        } else {
            _log.debug("The password didn't match");
            addActionError("The password you entered was incorrect, nothing was sent to the bank.");
            return ActionSupport.ERROR;
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
```

my jsp

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <div class="errors">
            <s:actionerror/>
            </div><br>
        </s:if>
```

again, this worked perfectly a month ago. All i did was check out that branch which has been untouched and deploy it. Now it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you trying to provide that data to the JSP?  Are you adding an action error?  Can you provide the code for your actions?

Comment: And you have this in your jsp:  `<s:actionerror/>` ?

Comment: am i right that when you route to another JSP following this type of workflow its supposed to bring the data in the original pages servlet with it?  i mean here is the entire checkaction class  `public class CheckAction extends ActionSupport {
 private Collection<Check> checkList;

 public Collection<Check> getCheckList() {
  return checkList;
 }

 public String execute() {
  checkList = Check.list();
  return SUCCESS;
 }
}`

Comment: The checkList data will not remain on the page afterwards.  It will persist for only the first request.

Comment: ok, so how would i do the redirectAction solution and still retain my error messages?

Comment: @scphantm You'd use the message store interceptor or roll your own flash scope interceptor or do it manually for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix could be to add this to `getCheckList` in the `CheckAction`:

```
public Collection<Check> getCheckList() { 
   ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("checkList", checkList);
   return checkList; 
}
```

and add this to the `SubmitFileAction`:

```
public Collection<Check> getCheckList() { 
   return (Collection<Check>) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("checkList"); 
}
```

This is not a good permanent solution but should get you where you need to get in a crunch!

Comment: beautiful.  that worked.  I can address it further later, thank you so very much.  i still don't understand how it worked a month ago.  i really don't.  when i don't have clients walking in the door i will check out a few revisions before and after and see if im missing something stupid or not.  but in the mean time, thank you very much, this saved my bacon.

Comment: it went great.  This was just a prototype app but we are going to move forward with this concept.  im working on the production version technology stack right now.    thanks a lot.